# Low Frequency Noise inside my house

Tags: plumbing, noise, sewer

I do live next to a sewer lift station.  The noise is through out my home.  It seems to be worse late night to early morning and when it's colder out.  Could the pump station noise be piped into my house?  I do also feel slight vibrations at times.   I thought maybe it could be the monitoring system they are using which has a giant antenna.  I don't know what to do, I really need help.  I cannot take the noise.  It can be so loud at times it hurts my ears.

Comment: file a complaint at city hall

Comment: Is this new? Are you new to the house?  Do you own or rent the house?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the antenna.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it ultimately boils down to a legal issue which is off-topic here.  We can’t hear or feel the noise from where we sit, so like finding the source of a smell we can’t really help.  The reality is, complain to the city and/or sewer district, document everything you and they do or say, if you remain unsatisfied seek legal advice.  If you’re a renter just give notice and move already, it’s the simple easy path.

Comment: is it only inside your home?  i'm hearing a low-frequency vibrating sound inside, but not outside the house...it's hell

Answer (score 3):

Many lift stations now use what are called "VFDs" (Variable Frequency Drives) to control the speed of the pumps. So instead of allowing the tank to fill up to trigger a pump to run full speed until it pumps down again, they use a continuous level monitor system and change the pump speed to adjust for variations in flow and the pumps never (or rarely) completely stop.

VFDs can cause electrical distribution transformers to make noise (due to what are called "harmonics"). If you are hearing this as an audible hum, it may be something they can fix, but they won't do it unless you complain.

The other possibility is that this is a mechanical issue with the pumps causing actual mechanical vibrations (seismic) getting to your house under certain circumstances that are conducive to that transmittal, i.e. ground moisture conditions are just right. In that case they SHOULD fix it, because it is an impending equipment failure. They may not know, so either way you should tell them.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question I have.  YES, I've complained and complained for some time now.  NO, I don't rent.  Tyson, sorry you feel this is off topic, however I assure you this is a real situation and maybe it's legal or will become legal however I wanted to see what answers are there.  YES, I know for sure it's the pump station.  AGAIN THANK YOU J Raefield for your answer, I very much appreciate it.

Comment: how far can this kind of noise travel on average?